# ApplicationInsightsWebTracking Failed with 500 Error

Tags: asp.net, .net, azure, azure-application-insights

ApplicationInsightsWebTracking failed with 500 status code in our app. Error message is
[image]

Here's the code for web.config:

```
<system.web>
    <authentication mode="None" />
    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.7.2" />
    <httpRuntime targetFramework="4.7.2" />
    <httpModules>
      <add name="ApplicationInsightsWebTracking" type="Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.Web.ApplicationInsightsHttpModule, Microsoft.AI.Web" />
    </httpModules>
    <customErrors mode="On" />
  </system.web>
```

The code to integrate with application insights is standard. Any idea on why this error may occur?

Answer (score 0):

- I have followed this [MSDoc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/app/asp-net) and able to track the Application Insights without any issues

[image]

[image]

- In `Web.config` => Under `<system.webServer>` tag , add the below line

> ```cs
>  <remove name="ApplicationInsightsWebTracking" />   
>  <add name="ApplicationInsightsWebTracking" type="Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.Web.ApplicationInsightsHttpModule, Microsoft.AI.Web" preCondition="managedHandler" />
> ```

- Make sure all the configuration files (***ApplicationInsights.config*** and ***Web.config***) are deployed to Azure Web App and Check whether they are under `wwwroot` directory.

Please refer [Diagnose exceptions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/app/asp-net-exceptions) for more information